# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'day' Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

someone help me to correct this error

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
```

This is a part of the code

```
        else: 
            
            mediaTemperatura = np.mean([dataFrame.iloc[t+2][0],dataFrame.iloc[t+1][0]])
                
            mediaPower = np.mean([dataFrame.iloc[t+2][1],dataFrame.iloc[t+1][1]])
                
            diaZerado = (str(dataFrame.index.year[t+1])+'-'+str(dataFrame.index.month[t+1])+
            '-'+str(dataFrame.index.day[t+1]) + " " + str(dataFrame.index.hour[t+1])+':00:00')
                
            dicTime["Horário"].append(diaZerado)
            dicTime["Temperatura"].append(mediaTemperatura)
            dicTime["Potência"].append(mediaPower)
            
    return dicTime
```

When I run this command:

```
start_time = time.time()
dicTime = completeTime(df)
print(f'Tempo de execução: {(time.time() - start_time) / 60} minutos')
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'day'

I am working at Jupyter

Comment: Probably because you assigned the word ```dataFrame``` to a ```dataFrame```

Comment: I am getting the same error with "strftime", it feels absurd. I have called the pd.Series object anything, even random words. Perhaps a bug in the latest Pandas?